# Can't find id when transforming number to string

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I have three images, each with their own id. First image's id = "1", second image's id = "2", third one's id = "3".

I have an array with three images. I would like to change the previously mentioned images to the ones within the array. To do this I have made a for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    var idString = (i).toString();
    document.getElementById(idString).src = myArray[i];
  }
```

However, it isn't able to get the id. If I replace idString with "2" then it switches the image with the id = "2" perfectly, so I know for sure that the problem is convering i to string to get the id.

Thank you for reading. Any help will be grealy appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post also the html, to turn your code in a [mcve] ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without seeing your DOM, it's impossible to tell why the `getElementById` call is failing. Is your DOM zero-indexed or one-indexed?

Comment: If your images start with ID 1, then at `i = 0` your code will throw an error because there is nothing with ID zero

Comment: Hey @VLAZ. Yeah this was the problem, it works now. Thanks a ton!

Thanks to everyone for the super quick answers. I am completely new to programming so I'm quite sure what things such as DOM are, but thanks a lot still for sending help my way.

Answer (score 1):

Your **for** loop is not starting at 1. Add 1 to i to get the IDs of the images.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    var idString = (i + 1).toString();
    document.getElementById(idString).src = myArray[i];
}
```